# Universal Algebra: partial algebras and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, universal-algebra

I'm looking for an accessible introductory text on universal algebra, one which discusses homomorphisms in the context of partial algebras.

I have been recommended the Grätzer book, "Universal Algebra", but I am not sure it is suitable.

I have studied introductory model theory and mathematical logic, and have some knowledge of set theory, but I have never studied algebra of this kind before and am not a mathematician.

What texts or notes, other than the Grätzer, treat of these topics in an accessible fashion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your concern about Gratzer?

Comment: Not being a mathematician (a mere philosophy student), and having only studied logic and model theory, the book seems to be for students who have been exposed to basic algebra (but perhaps I'm wrong here). Is that a fair assessment? In any case, you didn't answer my question: what texts other than the grätzer can you recommend?

Comment: I wasn't trying to answer your question (hence my comment was a comment, not an answer); and in fact your answer to my question effects my answer to yours :P, since now I have a better idea of what you're looking for. If you studied model theory from any of the books I'm familiar with, you'll have run into e.g. *groups* and *rings*, and possibly other structures; these will prepare you for the algebra part of Gratzer. Also, if you're willing to accept abstract definitions with minimal motivation, you should also be fine. I don't know of a more elementary book, but others might. (cont'd)

Comment: By the way,  if you've studied model theory you might find the following helpful: Universal algebra is the model theory of equations. For example, what sort of operations preserve equations, and can we use this to describe the class of models of a set of equations? (We can: this is the HSP theorem.) I think if your background in model theory is good, you'll be fine with Gratzer's book.

Comment: Apologies if my comment came across as aggressive (it certainly wasn't intended to be). All the model theory I know is from Enderton's intro to mathematical logic, which covers some model theoretic results, but is not at the level of Chang and Keisler's book on model theory (which I haven't read). So maybe I don't know enough model theory.  I have come across examples involving groups and rings from the enderton book, however. Let's hope this is sufficient!

Comment: Which of the books mentioned on this page http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/ would be of use, for example? Are any easier or the same level as the Grätzer?

Comment: Hm, good question. I'm not deeply familiar with those texts, so I'm just writing this as a comment: I think Ross Willard's article is very motivating and reasonably comprehensible.

Comment: Partial algebras are a rather specialised and quite technical topic. That's why I pointed you to Gratzer's rather encyclopaedic book in my answer to your earlier question. I advise you to try to flick through his discussion of partial algebras as well as following up the suggestions in other comments to this question.